# Error al incluir un archivo de webform en una vista para MVC C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, reportviewer, webforms

Junto con saludarles, quería solicitarle su gran ayuda:
Resulta que deseo incorporar en una vista, una parcial que es un webform:

Tengo una vista que se llama Ver:

```
public ActionResult Ver(){

return View();
}
```

en el cshtml llamo así al webform:

```
@Html.Partial("Mostrarejemplo")
```

Pero en esa misma linea de html.partial, me sale el siguiente error:

**La vista encontrada en '~/Views/Archivosnegocio/ImprimeDos.aspx' debe derivarse de ViewPage, ViewPage, ViewUserControl o ViewUserControl.**

Y el archivo webform(Mostrarejemplo) está ubicado en la misma ruta de donde llamo la vista.

Me gustaría que si alguien sabe, me ayude por favor, desde ya, gracias.

Nota: El objetivo de porque hago esto, es para poder tener la opción de vista previa del pdf que se genera con reportviewer,de la misma forma como lo indica está pagina de ejemplo:
http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/display-data-in-report-viewer-with-mvc-4/

ya que actualmente lo hago así:

```
    public FileContentResult GetFileContentResult(ReportParameter[] parametro, string nombreReporte, dynamic query, string nombreDataSource, String format, String deviceInfo, String fileDownloadName)
    {
        LocalReport report = new LocalReport();
        report.ReportPath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Reportes/" + nombreReporte);

        report.DataSources.Clear();
        //report.ReportEmbeddedResource="dd.rdlc";
        ReportDataSource reportDataSource = new ReportDataSource();
        reportDataSource.Value = query;
        reportDataSource.Name = nombreDataSource;
        report.DataSources.Add(reportDataSource);
        report.SetParameters(parametro);
        report.Refresh();


        String mimeType;
        String encoding;
        String filenameExtension;
        String[] streamIds;
        Warning[] warnings;

        FileContentResult fileContentResult = new FileContentResult(report.Render(format, deviceInfo, out mimeType, out encoding, out filenameExtension, out streamIds, out warnings), mimeType);
        fileContentResult.FileDownloadName = Path.ChangeExtension(fileDownloadName, filenameExtension);

        return fileContentResult;
    }
```

pero solo me descarga el pdf, y no me abre visualizandose como vista previa. Si fuera posible está solución, solucionaría mi objetivo. Cualquiera de las formas o ambas, me serían de gran aporte.

Comment: ¿Deseas incluir en tu vista parcial el archivo .aspx o solo deseas redieccionar? ¿O simplemente deseas que el PDF se muestre en el navegador?

Comment: Deseo incluir el archivo en mi vista parcial

Comment: Lo que veo es que siempre regresas un `FileContentResult` cuando lo mejor que sería que regresarás es un `string` con el contenido del PDF pero en HTML, para que en la vista solo pongas `@Html.Raw(htmlDelPDF)`, de esta forma, estarás escribiendo el directamente el HTML sin la necesidad de que te abra directamente el archivo generado.